# Why do some Rails helpers fail in Webpacker ERB file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, erb

In my Rails application I installed the Webpacker ERB module via **rails webpacker:install:erb**. I did not change the automatically generated configuration entries in **config/webpack/environment.js**. When I load the automatically generated pack file **hello_erb.js.erb**, the ERB templating succeeds. When I use the **content_tag** helper with passing the content as a parameter, it still works. But when I use it with a block instead (**do** keyword), it fails with an error message. Also some non-block helper calls fail. How can I fix this behavior?

I have tried the same code in the Rails views and there the ERB templating succeeds. I tried to change the parantheses and attributes, but it did not help.

```js
// Include native helpers (for `content_tag`)
<% include ActionView::Helpers %>

// This works. # => "<div>Example 1</div>"
console.log(`<%= content_tag(:div, 'Example 1') %>`);

// This fails. # => See below
console.log(`<%= content_tag(:div) do %>Example 2<% end %>`);
```

The last line of code of the example given above produces following error in the Rails console:

```
/home/anonymous/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval': (erb):7: syntax error, unexpected ')' (SyntaxError)
...out.<<(( content_tag(:div) do ).to_s); _erbout.<< "Example 2".f...
...                              ^
(erb):7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
...erbout.<< "Example 2".freeze;  end ; _erbout.<< "`);\n".freeze
...                            ^~~
(erb):8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
; _erbout
         ^
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
    from /home/anonymous/anonymous/node_modules/rails-erb-loader/erb_transformer.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/runner/runner_command.rb:38:in `perform'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    from /home/anonymous/anonymous/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/anonymous/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please note that I created an issue at the GitHub page of the project: https://github.com/usabilityhub/rails-erb-loader/issues/82